# How to create a contact form allowing to add multiple phone numbers in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, contacts

I'm creating a simple contacts app in django and I want to allow everyone to have more than a single phone number.

My models.py looks like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

I need to create a form where I can add the core contact info and as many phone numbers as wanted.

I have a ModelForm like

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

How do I create a phone_number field which allows to insert the phone number?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: pleas post the solution code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial that is perhaps a bit more helpful than the documentation if you're struggling:
http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

It goes through using formsets which allow you to have and use more than one form of the same type on a page.
And also shows you a JQuery plugin that allows you to add and remove forms dynamically.